# How can I instantiate windows form objects for multiple clients in C #

Tags: c#, multithreading

I tried to instantiate an object of the **WebBrowser** class to make a query on a page and return a result but an error is generated:

> An instance of the ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be created because the Current thread is not in a unprocessed container.

I have tried to implement this in different ways but I do not achieve the desired result.

Here is my code

```
// At beginig of class Form
public delegate void DataRecieved(ConexionTcp conexionTcp, string data);
public event DataRecieved OnDataRecieved;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnDataRecieved += MensajeRecibido;
}
private void MensajeRecibido(ConexionTcp conexionTcp, string datos)
{
    WebBrowser myweb= new WebBrowser();
    myweb.Navigate("http://localhost/Php/Final3");
    myweb.Document.GetElementById("user").InnerText = "user";
    myweb.Document.GetElementById("pass").InnerText = "pass";
    myweb.Document.GetElementById("Encode").InvokeMember("Click");
    if ("resultado" == myweb.Document.GetElementById("pass_sha_hash").InnerText)
    { 
        textbox1.Text="Completado";
    }
}
```

Can anyone find out what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide more context about the function? specifically how you are invoking this function?

Comment: this function is called when a message is recibe from a client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to access a Windows Form Control from a thread.

Accessing Windows Form Controls from another thread is not safe. So you are getting this error.

Please refer this document for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls

You can use Background Threads to do your operation. Otherwise marking the thread's apartment state to STA might help.

In the below example, I have used STA thread, otherwise, I will get a similar error.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread t;
    public delegate void DataRecieved();
    public event DataRecieved OnDataRecieved;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.TriggerEvent));

        // Make sure that you are using STA
        // Otherwise you will get an error when creating WebBrowser
        // control in the Navigate method
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();

        OnDataRecieved += Navigate;
    }

    public void Navigate()
    {
        WebBrowser b = new WebBrowser();
        b.Navigate("www.google.com");
    }

    public void TriggerEvent()
    {

        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        OnDataRecieved();
    }
}
```

Below is the error:

```
System.Threading.ThreadStateException: 'ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.'
```

Hope this helps.